# Regex failing to match number and dash with letter (or space and letter)

Tags: regex, postgresql

In the [tester](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) this works ... but not in PostgreSQL.

My data is like this -- usually a series of letters, followed by 2 numbers and a POSSIBLE '-' or 'space' with only ONE letter following. I am trying to isolate the 2 numbers and the Possible '-" or 'space' AND the ONE letter with my regex:

For ex:

```
AJ 50-R Busboys ## should return 50-R
APPLES 30 F ## should return 30 F 
FOOBAR 30 Apple ## should return 30
```

Regex's (that have worked in the tester, but not in PostgreSQL) that I've tried:

```
substring(REF from '([0-9]+)-?([:space:])?([A-Za-z])?')
```

&

```
substring(REF from '([0-9]+)-?([A-Za-z])?')
```

So far everything tests out in the tester...but not the PostgreSQL. I just keep getting the numbers returns -- AND NOTHING AFTER IT.

What I am getting now(for ex):

```
AJ 50-R Busboys ## returns as "50" NOT as "50-R"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for: `substring(REF from '([0-9]+(-| )([A-Za-z]\y)?)')`

In [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/496/1). Your primary problem is that `substring` returns the first or outermost matching group (ie., pattern surrounded with `()`), which is why you get 50 for your '50-R'. If you were to surround the entire pattern with `()`, this would give you '50-R'. However, the pattern you have fails to return what you want on the other strings, even after accounting for this issue, so I had to modify the entire regex.

Comment: The combination of the lookahead and `*` here: `([A-Za-z](?= |$))*` confuses me a bit.  Does it differ significantly from something like:  `([A-Za-z]\y)?`

Comment: No, and I've updated my answer to use this simple syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @ Matthew -- you definitely gave me something to learn today '\y'...your answer was right around what I was looking for (had to make some edits since I needed to still return a number even IF there was no following letters or digits -- so "US 6" still needed to get the "6"). thanks!

Comment: Actually, [`\M` is correct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE). `\y` works, too, in this particular case.

Comment: [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/508 )   I used: '(([0-9]+)[-|\s]?([A-Za-z]\y)?)'

Comment: @user14696: I think the `|` in your character class is a misunderstanding. That would make sense for *branches*. Consider updated fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/533

Answer (score 2):

This matches your description and examples.
<sub>Your description is slightly ambiguous. Leading letters are followed by *a space* and then two digits in your examples, as opposed to your description.</sub>

```sql
SELECT t, substring(t, '^[[:alpha:] ]+(\d\d(:?[\s-]?[[:alpha:]]\M)?)')
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('AJ 50-R Busboys')       -- should return: 50-R
    ,('APPLES 30 F')           -- should return: 30 F 
    ,('FOOBAR 30 Apple')       -- should return: 30
    ,('FOOBAR 30x Apple')      -- should return: 30x
    ,('sadfgag30 D 66 X foo')  -- should return: 30 D - not: 66 X
   ) r(t);
```

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7bc0e/1)

#### Explanation

`^` .. start of string (last row could fail without anchoring to start and global flag `'g'`). Also: faster.
`[[:alpha:] ]+` .. one or more letters or spaces (like in your examples).
`(` ..  capturing parenthesis
`\d\d` .. two digits
`(:?` .. non-capturing parenthesis
`[\s-]?` .. `'-' or 'white space'` (character class), 0 or 1 times
`[[:alpha:]]` .. 1 letter
`\M` .. followed by end of word (can be end of string, too)
`)?` .. the pattern in non-capturing parentheses 0 or 1 times

Letters as defined by the [character class `alpha`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) according to the current locale! The poor man's substitute `[a-zA-Z]` only works for basic ASCII letters and fails for anything more. Consider this simple demo:

```sql
SELECT  substring('oö','[[:alpha:]]*')
       ,substring('oö','[a-zA-Z]*');
```

[More about character classes in Postgres regular expressions in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS)

Comment: @ Erwin -- you nailed it. For the case you added, as you noticed I didn't turn on the global flag (hence 66 X wasn't a worry), but you made a good point that [[:alpha:]] is >> then [a-zA-Z]. The dataset I am working in is ASCII only -- but I've been having fun with utf-8 characters in various regex problems...ran into some problems with Chinese numerals in both python and postgresql (i.e. they were not being recognized as numbers -- but as you noted changing the local in postgresql was the key). Thanks!

Comment: @user14696: Nice. I clarified the part you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the parentheses.

I've looked everywhere in the documentation and found an interesting sentence on [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> [...] if the pattern contains any parentheses, the portion of the text that matched the first parenthesized subexpression (the one whose left parenthesis comes first) is returned.

I took your first expression:

```
([0-9]+)-?([:space:])?([A-Za-z])?
```

and wrapped it in parentheses:

```
(([0-9]+)-?([:space:])?([A-Za-z])?)
```

and it works fine (see [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/486)).

### Update:

Also, because you're looking for `-` or space, you could rewrite your middle expression to `[-|\s]?` (thanks [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433829/matthew-plourde) for pointing that out), which leads to the following possible REGEX:

```
(([0-9]+)[-|\s]?([A-Za-z])?)
```

([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/491))

Update 2:

While my answer provides the explanation as to why the result represented a partial match of your expression, the expression I presented above fails your third test case.

You should use the regex provided by Matthew in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338368/390819).

Comment: This fails on the second and third strings.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde +1 BTW :)

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Right! Now I noticed that last requirement. I'll leave  it like that, as your answer provides the correct regex.

Comment: @ w0lf & Matthew: Thanks, +1 for the input.