# Deleting dynamic links from string

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, replace, postgresql-9.3

In a Postgres database (9.3) I have strings like these from which I intend to delete the links:

```
'HV 3 STANKOVERLAST (+Inc,net: reg.inmeld+) , J.J. Cremerplein 46 AMSTERDAM [ ASD ] http:\/\/t.co\/qzmyMibvHn #p2000'
'A1 13105 AMSTERDAM Bickersgracht 270 http:\/\/t.co\/4oX6B5oAo4 #p2000'
'A1 13157 AMSTERDAM Argonautenstraat 54 3 http:\/\/t.co\/mmyjBcWEFY #p2000'
'A1 13122 AMSTERDAM Tweede Helmersstraat 6 Hotel Crystal http:\/\/t.co\/BWGj4R1noh #p2000'
```

To delete them, I used:

```
split_part(text, 'http', 1)
```

Unfortunately, not all of them are build the same way with the link in the end:

```
'BR 2 BUITENBRAND (+http:\/\/t.co\/1x4jPyfA9e: reg.inmeld+) Ferdinand Bolstraat , Quellijnstraat AMSTERDAM [ ASD ] #p2000 #watiserloos'
```

Using `split_part()` here would delete big parts of this string

I already looked for some kind of regex function, but couldn't find a solution for these dynamic links.

Comment: Please define *exactly* what you want to cut and what should stay. Use more examples.

Comment: I wanna delete the part of string beginning with http until the next space. For my first example this would be 'http:\/\/t.co\/qzmyMibvHn'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use [`regexp_replace()` or `substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) with [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to cut most anything from your strings, as long as you can define it clearly.

In your case, something like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string, 'http:[^[:space:]]+(:?\s*#p\d+)?', '') AS trimmed
```

Or simpler, according to your later comment:

> the part of string beginning with http until the next space

(or end of string, I may add)

```
SELECT regexp_replace(string, 'http:[^[:space:]]+', '') AS trimmed
```

Replaces the first occurrence of the pattern. Add the [global switch `'g'`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), if there can be more.

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/526)

#### Explain

`[^[:space:]]` .. character class of all non-whitespace character.
`^` .. negates the class.
`[:space:]` .. character class for white space [characters as defined by your locale](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS).
Cuts any part starting with `http:` up to the next white space character. Plus, optionally,  a dangling `#p` followed by a number.
`+` .. one or more atoms

More explanation under this recent, related question:
[Regex failing to match number and dash with letter (or space and letter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337643/regex-failing-to-match-number-and-dash-with-letter-or-space-and-letter)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works fine for me. But at the moment i don't really understand what is going on in the ''http:[^[:space:]]+(:?\s*#p\d+)?'' part. Can you tell me which syntax this is following?

Comment: @user2878448: I added a simpler solution for your updated request with some explanation. For information on the syntax, follow the link to the manual I left for you under "regular expressions" in the first line. And some more detailed explanation in the related answer I linked to.

Comment: Thanks again. Explanation was helpful as the link. I would upvote if i could.